# Reliable memcached pool

Tags: caching, memcached, couchbase

I currently having below issue: I run multiple memcached instances across various servers,  if any of the server go down, my application screws up(increases hits to backend). Should I use moxi or couchbase ?. I don't want to change in my code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use memcached today, install Moxi on each application server and point it at a Couchbase cluster with a Couchbase bucket. That is the whole idea around moxi. It is meant to be that bridge between memcached and Couchbase. Just do not make the mistake that some people do and install Couchbase on the same nodes as your application servers like some do with memcached.

Just know that you will not get the full features that Couchbase offers, as some of that requires the SDKs, but you will get the pieces it sounds like you need initially.